# Do you mind checking my grammar in a presentation about my family?

Tags: grammar, writing-critique

I have to make a presentation about my family. Would you mind checking the grammar for me?

> Zhè shì wo de jiā rén. Wo jiā you liu kou ren. You bàba, māma, gege, jiejie, didi he wo. Wo bàba he māma dou xianzai tuìxiū le. Rújīn tamen xihuan lüxíng. Wo gege he jie jie dou jiéhūn le. Wo jiali mei ge ren hen cong ming, women jiali you san wei yisheng.

Comment: jiārén 家人 usu. written as one wd,  : why not indicate all (not neutral) tones? : ren, you,liang,  on 1st syllable: gege, jiejie, didi,etc.dou xianzai-> xianzai dou （see previous disc. of order of adverbial modifiers), xihuan-＞ hen xihuan (if 喜欢 is entered in jukuu, w/o hen, get negations with adverb bu or questions）but get many samples for   hen xihuan,bu zhu zai women de jiā: omit "de",cong-> congming 聪明,

Comment: some users also thought that 在我们家里 (zai women jia li) is more common than 在我们家了 (zai women jia le) （了 for "no longer"  indicating change) so they entered 在我们家 into jukuu and got many samples: with 在我们家 "in our home/house" 我妻子娘家的人目前住在我们家。他们在我们家呆了一夜。

Answer (score 2):

original:
這是我的家人。
我家有六口人。
有爸爸、媽媽、哥哥、兩個姊姊、弟弟和我。
我爸爸和媽媽都現在退休了。
如今他們喜歡旅行。
我哥哥和兩個姊姊都結婚了。
他們不住在我們的家了。
我弟弟很聰。
他是醫生。
我愛我家人。

suggest:
我爸爸和媽媽都(現在)退休了。 remove 現在
他們(現在)不住在我家。 add 現在
我弟弟很聰(明)。 add 明
我愛我(的)家人。 add 的

pinyin:
這是我的家人。
(Zhè shì wǒ de jiā rén.)
我家有七個人。 有爸爸、媽媽、哥哥、兩個姊姊、弟弟和我。
(Wǒ jiā yǒu qī gè rén. Yǒu bàba, māmā, gēgē, liǎng gè jiě jie, dìdì hé/hàn wǒ.)
我爸爸和媽媽都退休了。 如今他們喜歡旅行。
(Wǒ bàba hé/hàn māmā dōu tuì xiū le. Rú jīn tā men xǐ huān lǚ xíng.)
我哥哥和兩個姊姊都結婚了。 他們現在不住在我家。
(Wǒ gēgē hé/hàn liǎng gè jiě jie dōu jié hūn le. Tā men xiàn zài bù zhù zài wǒ jiā.)
我弟弟很聰明。 他是醫生。
(Wǒ dìdì hěn cōng míng. Tā shì yī shēng.)
我愛我的家人。
(Wǒ ài wǒ de jiā rén.)

Comment: suggestion:
不住 should be (bú zhù)
https://zh.m.wiktionary.org/zh/%E4%B8%8D
(註解: 后接第四声时变调为 bú)

Answer (score 0):

Zhè shì wö de jiā rén. Wö jiā yöu qī gè rén. Yöu bàba, māma, gēge, liäng gè jië jie, `hái yöu` dìdi hé wö. Wö bàba he māma `xiàn zài dōu` tuì xiū le, Rú jīn tā men xï huān lü xíng. Wö gēge hé liäng ge jië jie dōu jié hūn le, `suö yï` tā men bú zhù zài wö men `jiā lï` le. Wö dì di hën `cōng ming`, tā shì yī shēng. Wö ài wö `de` jiā rén.

I marked all the tones of the words, and correct some mistakes, such as grammar, words, and punctuations.

Answer (score 0):

Zhè shì wo de jiā rén. Wo jiā you qi ge ren. You bàba, māma, gege, liang ge jie jie, didi he wo. Wo bàba he māma **xianzai dou** tuìxiū le. Rújīn tamen xihuan lüxíng. Wo gege he liang ge jie jie dou jiéhūn le. Tamen bu zhu zai women de jiā le. Wo di di hen **cong ming**. Ta shi Yisheng. Wo ai wo jia ren.